# Set up granular design permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, external-users

I am using SharePoint Online and have been asked to give a third party access to the site so that they can change out text and images, but not be able to change the layout. I don't think this can be done. My understanding is that design permissions don't get that granular. You either have access or you don't. I have looked around to see if it's possible but didn't turn anything up. Is there any way I can set up such access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your description, I understand that you want to grant external users permissions to allow them changing text and images, but not be able to change the layout on a **page**?

I'm afraid OOTB it is currently not supported in SharePoint as per my knowledge.